# C++: Mathematical function for Heatmap (BMP)

Tags: c++, heatmap, bmp

I am trying to write a program that generates a Heatmap from Force Sources. As of now, using the force in every pixel, I calculate the Color compounds using gaussian distributions (or simply `exp(-(x*x))`). After norming it to always give me some colour, the picture looks like this: [image]

This features two sources, at the center of the blue spots.

It looks cool, but the transition between the colours isn't fluid at all, and it has black lines as you can see. I tried moving around the exponential functions, making them less steep, and norming them to always equal 255 in total. This is the best result I got using that.

So, my Question: Is there a function that's better suited than e^-x² for this Problem? Or, is there something I can add to the function to make it a more fluid transition?

In case someone wants a code example, this is the function I'm using to write the bmp:

```
void Field::toBmp(std::ofstream& fp)
{
    BmpWriter::writeHeader(x_dim, y_dim, fp);
    char buffer[x_dim*y_dim*3 + 54];
    int myconst = 10;
    int normalizer;
    const int MAX = 1000;
    unsigned int pow = 0;
    for(unsigned int index = 0; index < y_dim; index++)
    {
        for(unsigned int counter = 0; counter < x_dim; counter++)
        {
            pow = calculateForce(counter, index) * myconst;
            if(pow > MAX)
            {
            buffer[(index*x_dim + counter)*3 + 0] = 0X00;

            buffer[(index*x_dim + counter)*3 + 1] = 0X00;

            buffer[(index*x_dim + counter)*3 + 2] = 0XFF;
            }

            else
            {
                std::cout << pow << '\n';
                buffer[(index*x_dim + counter)*3 + 0] = 255*exp((-std::pow((pow),2.0)/(256*256)));

                buffer[(index*x_dim + counter)*3 + 1] = 255*exp((-std::pow((pow-(MAX/2),2.0))/(256*256));

                buffer[(index*x_dim + counter)*3 + 2] = 255*exp((-std::pow((pow-MAX),2.0)/(256*256)));

                normalizer = 255/(buffer[(index*x_dim + counter)*3 + 2] 
                    + buffer[(index*x_dim + counter)*3 + 1] 
                    + buffer[(index*x_dim + counter)*3 + 2] + 0.01);
                buffer[(index*x_dim + counter)*3 + 2] *= normalizer;
                buffer[(index*x_dim + counter)*3 + 1] *= normalizer;
                buffer[(index*x_dim + counter)*3 + 0] *= normalizer;
            }

        }
    }
    fp.write(buffer, x_dim*y_dim*3);
}
```

Comment: What is the issue with the current framework? Looking at the image it appears to be well rendered and generally for scientific data (which is generally the application of heatmaps) you don't want to manipulate the data for aesthetic purposes. Regardless, have you looked at a blurring function?

Comment: @ChrisBritt thanks! I guess you're right, it serves its purpose. I am doing it as a learning exercise and to check the implementation of  a potential field algorithm later on, and I just wasn't happy with the thin darker lines within the green area for example.

Comment: Try also the new http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For doing interpolations in color, it is not optimal to do it in RGB-space. I'd use HSV or HSL (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV). Doing this, you could set your Saturation and Value or Saturation and Lightness to a constant value, then map your data to various Hue's. You'd do this pixel-by-pixel (generate each pixel's color based on it's hue) and then apply a HSL or HSV to RGB conversion function to find the RGB for that pixel for your BMP (these are easy enough to find via google).

Comment: I should note, I've had to create images that represent magnitude data over certain areas. Using an HSL color palette was the only way I found to create smooth color gradients without altering the underlying data. It does make it visually appealing.

Comment: This is amazing, thanks! If I understand it correctly, I'd only need one conversion from Force to HSL value, and then one to RGB? So not three operations as I have them currently? Seems like a nice bonus on top!

Comment: Well to be fair... you need one conversion from force to HSL (or more likely, one conversion from force to Hue with a fixed saturation and lightness), but the conversion from HSL to RGB requires more math than probably generating the RGB components seperately from force. It will look better, the code to do it shouldn't be slow by any means, but it will probably be slower than your old code. From your standpoint though, it is just 2 conversions (all that math happens in your HSL to RGB function, which you can find pretty easily on google/SO)

Comment: Okay after looking at the code, I guess you're right. Have you thought about using a  predefined (sorted) array of hue values (around 100 values)? I think it would be quite fast, to simply calculate the power, use it as a percentage of MAX, and print that hue's RGB value for the pixel in question. After all, if saturation and lightness are fixed you only need hue, right?

Comment: @BigBadWolf You could do that if you wanted. In my use I actually used Sat and Lightness to represent other pieces of data so it wouldn't have been quite as easy. But for you, if you wanted to make a LUT that should be fine. Realistically though, the code isn't that slow. If you are just making a BMP it would probably add on the order of milliseconds or less to your run time. Now if you were trying to make a heatmap video rendered in real-time I'd probably put the effort into a LUT.